# How to generate the similar folding effect as Gmail in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I assume Gmail used JavaScript to implement the folding effect for a particular email thread. The effect I am talking about is: after you choose a particular email thread by clicking on it, then you will see that only the latest email is shown, with all the previous emails in a folded state. Only when you click on the folding section, they will expand, but still only showing a snippet of them. Then you click on each individual section, you can read the full message. How can one do this? Many thanks.

Comment: Which effect are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the effect where previous messages in a thread are collapsed so just the sender's name and the first few words of the message are shown.

How I would do it: For every message other than unread ones, load the sender's name and the first *n* characters of the body. Display all the previous messages in a table with an onclick listener on each row. When the row is clicked, use Ajax to retrieve the full message from the server and replace the truncated message with the full one. If the user clicks the row again, hide the full message except for the first *n* characters. In GMail's case, the unread and/or most recent messages are loaded in full when you click on an e-mail thread.

A simpler way to do it would be: Load all messages in full when the page loads, but hide all but *n* characters of the full message until the row is clicked. This will make the coding easier since you don't have to mess with Ajax and saving space on the screen, but wont give you the other benefits of less bandwidth usage.

Comment: I don't know why you think the OP intention is to know about performance in not loading the whole mails before needed when he doesn't mention any of that (which will be really relevant if you have so much data, but we don't know how much data he handles).

Comment: @Protron - Did you have a point? Why else would you want to hide data? Either to free up screen space or save on bandwidth. Both of which I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is really simple to make that nice visual effect (if you know enough javascript and jQuery). The [**toggle** function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is the function that will do the effect.

The [**accordion** control of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is really similar to what gmail does for threads. The differences is that the accordion allows only one section open at once, and in gmail several mails can be open at once.

So I recommend you to use the code in below the accordion example which allows multiple sections open at once, and not the accordion control itself for that matter.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Comment: There is no accordion effect in gmail. He's not talking about a visual effect anyway, he's talking about the organization of messages.

Comment: I actually said that gmail HAD NOT an accordion effect (because has multiple sections open at once). So we agree on that. What we don't agree is the OP intention. I don't know why are you so sure he is talking about how to "load" the content, instead of how to "show" that content (being "show" a verb in the question, while "load", "ajax", and "performance" are not being mentioned at all).